# grails save() method throws an transactionStatus error

Tags: grails

No such property: transactionStatus for class: org.siti.TicketController.

The error occurs here:

```
if (ticket.hasErrors()) {
        transactionStatus.setRollbackOnly()
        respond ticket.errors, view:'edit'
        return
    }
```

but the controller imports 
**import grails.transaction.Transactional**
and the controller is annotated with @Transactional(readOnly = true)
grails version 3.2.4

Comment: I can't reproduce that.  Please file an issue at https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues and provide a sample app which demonstrates the problem and we can take a look.  Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: Did you annotate the method (not the controller) with @Transactional ?
By the way, importing Transactional is not transactionStatus. It is hard to help you out if you only showed a snippet of code. We need to see the method definition and even the controller one.

Comment: Hi Jeff,  I'm sorry, but in a newly created demo application, I cannot reproduce that. In original application I try to save Date having wrong format, but have no validation message on the view, because the controller throws the No such property: transactionStatus for class error first.

Comment: @nbkhope "By the way, importing Transactional is not transactionStatus." - The original question indicates that he not only imported the annotation but also says that the controller is annotated with `@Transactional`.  That should cause the `transactionStatus` property to be added to the class at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

Try getting rid og the readOnly=true and just go with plain @Transactional.
If it is read only, what are you rolling back?